# What to brew in the summer?

Tags: fermentation-temperature

What kind of beer can I brew in the summer (30C by day, a few less by night), without special cooling equipment? Anything special (but not too complicated/expensive) I should do?

Comment: Why not a steam beer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_beer). They say ferment with lager yeast at ale temperatures but 30C would likely work too. Or you could do a hefewiezen with a nice estery yeast and the high temperature should increase those byproducts. But you are going to want to let whatever you do brew sit and let the fusel alcohols dissipate. A less alcoholic beer should have less of those so a hefe or even session beers of many styles would be prudent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saisons are great warm temp beers typically brewed during the summer. Typically saison yeast is pitched at a temperature around 20C° and then raised a few degrees each day until you hit ~26° While 30° seems on the high end for saison its doable; fermenting higher will likely result in increased fruity or spicy character.

You don't necessarily need any complicated equipment to brew a normal ale. You could utilize any tub of water and ice packs to keep a fermenter cool. See this Question for more information.

[Would placing the fermenter tank in a tub of water be a good way to handle hot environments?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/would-placing-the-fermenter-tank-in-a-tub-of-water-be-a-good-way-to-handle-hot-e/9789#9789)

Answer (score 1):

saison/farm house ales. I was planning on for this summer as well :) They do well in the higher temperatures. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saison

Comment: Can you provide more details about why you recommend saison/farmhouse ales?