# Running a PRB or Star San solution through an Evaporative Cooler

Tags: starsan, swamp-cooler

(This is only tangentially related to brewing by virtue of Starsan and PWB - feel free to close if this is inappropriate)

I have an evaporative cooler, better known as a swamp cooler, that I use in place of AC. It works by drawing water onto a particular material and then blowing a fan across the wet material; the evporation has a localized cooling effect. [We use the same principal](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/would-placing-the-fermenter-tank-in-a-tub-of-water-be-a-good-way-to-handle-hot-e) to keep our fermentation temperatures down if we don't have a fermentation refrigerator.

I haven't turned it on since last summer and figure it could be somewhat dirty-- at the minimum, some organic material, and at the maximum, some gross infection.

Would it be fine for me to run water with PRB and/or starsan in it to clean it out?

Comment: I believe it depends on "a particular material" you are using. Without knowing what is it, we cannot know how it would react with cleaning solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out what material the chiller is made of and then you can find the proper cleaner to use. If it is stainless almost anything that isn't chlorine based would be fine to use. Aluminum on the other hand doesn't fare well with oxygen based cleaners. If it is copper oxalic acid would be best such as the product bar keepers friend.